# VSCode: How to exit as root user?

Tags: visual-studio-code, root

I have installed Kali Linux on my system. Installed VSCode to program in Python. I am getting a warning notification in VS Code -

```
"It is not recommended to run Code as a root user."
```

I know the harms of using it as a superuser. I don't know how to exit this mode. Please, help.

Honestly, I have searched the web and nowhere I can find a proper working solution.

Comment: Don't be logged in as root or su when you start VSCode. You should not run as root or su for what you do on a normal basis; you should only use root or su when you specifically need to do something that requires those privileges.

Comment: I get it sir, but now whenever I open VS Code, it gets open with a privilege of Super User by default. Please, provide me the solution of getting out of it.

Comment: It's only opening with *a privilege of Super User by default* because you're running as su before you start it. You should not be using su except when absolutely needed; you should be doing everything normally under a regular user (non-su) account. You're apparently not. You should find a *nix tutorial that explains how user accounts work and when you need su and (more importantly) when you do not.

Comment: How do you exit the mode?

Answer (score 1):

You started VScode with a root account so you need to switch users to a user on the system in the VS Terminal.

root@blah: su [user account to change to]

If your user account on kali is user3956566

For ex.: root@blah: su user3956566